# How to sum the value for each

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have table following :

```
ClientNUM    PIECES   DID
NEWAGENC     10       5
NEWAGENC     25       5
WAY          30       4
CHCAH        20       2
AVC          21       2
```

i want the **Result** that sum the value for each client as below

```
 CleintNUM     Pieces    DID
  NEWAGENC      35        5
  WAY           30        4
  CHCAH         20        2
  AVC          21         2
```

My query

```
SELECT  
      CLIENTNUM,
       DID, 
       PIECES,   
       GETDATE() AS CURRENTDATE, 
       SUM(PIECES)
FROM  Mytable
GROUP BY CLIENTNUM, DISPID, PIECES
```

So how can i do the sum for each `CLIENTNUM` in my query Means DISTINCT For each client Pieces like NEWAGENC has value 10 and in second row 25 so the pieces will be 10+ 25 = 35

Comment: Please show the results you want, and describe why the results you actually get are not what you want.

Comment: @MatBailie the second part that is mark as 'Result' i want as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't group by `PIECES` if you want to aggregate it

```
SELECT CLIENTNUM,
       DID, 
       PIECES,   
       GETDATE() AS CURRENTDATE, 
       SUM(PIECES)
FROM  Mytable
GROUP BY CLIENTNUM, DISPID
```

Comment: the error is Column 'Mytable.PIECES' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: That can't be. It is aggregated with `sum(pieces)`. Is that the real query or is the real one more complicated?

Comment: Sorry its working perfect . I was made a mistake. I have upvote your answer